# Rails | Session & Search Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, search

I have to get a `business_model` data as session when user clicks to link such as;

```
http://localhost:3000/tr/booking_requests/new?business_model=Sleep
```

I also have a search button, where we can search for a user name. After search the url becomes;

```
http://localhost:3000/tr/booking_requests/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Bill
```

So, `business_model` disappears. Normally, I take this params and assign it to a session

```
session[:business_model] = params[:business_model]
```

But once you click to search button new action kicks in and session becomes nil.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

When user clicks to link it goes to `new` action and session is stored.

```
def new
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order('id DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    @booking = BookingRequest.new
    session[:business_model] = params[:business_model]
  end
```

But when we click to search button. The request goes to `new` action again without `business_model` params. So it becomes nil. How can I store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the `new` controller action for something else. 1 action == 1 request. It seems that you are trying to both load the `new` form and also perform a search in the same action.

One approach would be to have a `search` action that does not set the `session[:business_model]` variable. This action can read from the session to make the search results relevant if you need it to and then render the `new` form.

Alternatively, it may be that the session is not the right approach here and you should really be persisting the `business_model` in a hidden form field so that it's resubmitted each time.